# ¿Cómo optimizar un código hecho en Django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy realizando una página en Django. El modelo es de un Product que tiene una Marca. El problema es que, quiero mostrar todas las marcas en el nav así se muestran solo los productos de esa marca. Lo pude hacer pero tuve que poner este codigo en todas las views:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['marca_list'] = Marca.objects.all()
    return context
```

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer esto una sola view y que esté incluido en el nav?

Comment: Puedes extender una clase en todas las views que sobrescribe ese método o usar un [`context_processors`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66051857/5721584) lo cual va a inyectar datos en cada petición

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La solución utilizada fue usar [context_processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893724/creating-my-own-context-processor-in-django/66051857#66051857)

Aca dejo un [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eWLaL2g1bo) con toda la explicación

Comment: Por favor agrega los detalles de la solución aqui y solo deja el video como referencia, ya que si en algún momento el mismo deja de estar disponible entonces la respuesta pierde contenido, checa [answer]